# how to make an image inline with text in HTML

Tags: html, css, image

I am working on an HTML project and I want to make the van image be in line with the heading Vintage Camper Rentals.
This is the code:

```
    <head>
    <title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="vintage1-logo.jpg">
    <li><a href="Index.html" target="blank" style="color: green; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-us.html" target="blank" style="color: green; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact-us.html" target="blank" style="color: green; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">Contact Us</a></li>
    <h1 style="color: blue; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 24pt;">Vintage Camper Rentals</h1>
    <div style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12pt; float: left;">We specialise in Classic Retro VW Kombi camper van hire and Modern camper rental, or depending on where you come from, Microbus, Vanagon, T4 Transporter or Combi hire.
        Our stylish VW campervans combine the best of the old and the new, contrasting the legendary status of retro VW campers with updated features for a comfy, fun time.
    </div>
    <h2 style="color: lightblue; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 18pt;">Booking your camper today</h2>
    <img src="vintage2-image.jpg" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;"><br>
    <img src="vintage3-footer.png">
    <p>Copyright 2020© - site designed by <a href="https://www.ajman.ac.ae" target="blank" style="color: green; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">Adnan Adel</p>    
</body>
```

Comment: Any CSS code Of your project

Comment: and can you roughly draw how you want things to look like

Comment: I am using inline styling because I did not learn how to make external CSS file yet @ash

Comment: ok @jamal but can you roughly draw an image. How you want things to look like

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use flexbox to make more items be inline, I wrapped the image and the `h1` tag in a `div` and added the `display` of `flex` to the wrapper, I also added an external property, `align-items` to center the text with the image.

Note: I changed the `src` of the images with a placeholder image for the snippet, you need to change the `src` attribute with your images.

```html
<li><a href="Index.html" target="blank" style="color: green; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-us.html" target="blank" style="color: green; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact-us.html" target="blank" style="color: green; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">Contact Us</a></li>
        
        
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
     <h1 style="color: blue; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times,      serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 24pt;">Vintage Camper        Rentals</h1>
    </div>
    
    
    <div style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12pt; float: left;">We specialise in Classic Retro VW Kombi camper van hire and Modern camper rental, or depending on where you come from, Microbus, Vanagon, T4 Transporter or Combi hire.
        Our stylish VW campervans combine the best of the old and the new, contrasting the legendary status of retro VW campers with updated features for a comfy, fun time.
    </div>
    <h2 style="color: lightblue; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 18pt;">Booking your camper today</h2>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;"><br>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <p>Copyright 2020© - site designed by <a href="https://www.ajman.ac.ae" target="blank" style="color: green; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">Adnan Adel</p>
```